# how to get latest App version from itunes

Tags: objective-c

i Want to forcefully update app to user for this i have used https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=1240084177 but i am getting no version if i use same url for paytm app with app id 473941634, then getting total response is

```
 {
"resultCount": 1,
"results": [{
    "artistViewUrl": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/developer/paytm-mobile-solutions/id473941637?uo=4",
    "artworkUrl60": "http://is2.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple118/v4/89/40/71/89407142-20e2-fb81-d9c8-1072ea8ee963/source/60x60bb.jpg",
    "artworkUrl100": "http://is2.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple118/v4/89/40/71/89407142-20e2-fb81-d9c8-1072ea8ee963/source/100x100bb.jpg",
    "appletvScreenshotUrls": [],
    "ipadScreenshotUrls": [],
    "artworkUrl512": "http://is2.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple118/v4/89/40/71/89407142-20e2-fb81-d9c8-1072ea8ee963/source/512x512bb.jpg",
    "kind": "software",
    "features": [],
    "supportedDevices": ["iPad2Wifi-iPad2Wifi", "iPad23G-iPad23G", "iPhone4S-iPhone4S", "iPadThirdGen-iPadThirdGen", "iPadThirdGen4G-iPadThirdGen4G", "iPhone5-iPhone5", "iPodTouchFifthGen-iPodTouchFifthGen", "iPadFourthGen-iPadFourthGen", "iPadFourthGen4G-iPadFourthGen4G", "iPadMini-iPadMini", "iPadMini4G-iPadMini4G", "iPhone5c-iPhone5c", "iPhone5s-iPhone5s", "iPadAir-iPadAir", "iPadAirCellular-iPadAirCellular", "iPadMiniRetina-iPadMiniRetina", "iPadMiniRetinaCellular-iPadMiniRetinaCellular", "iPhone6-iPhone6", "iPhone6Plus-iPhone6Plus", "iPadAir2-iPadAir2", "iPadAir2Cellular-iPadAir2Cellular", "iPadMini3-iPadMini3", "iPadMini3Cellular-iPadMini3Cellular", "iPodTouchSixthGen-iPodTouchSixthGen", "iPhone6s-iPhone6s", "iPhone6sPlus-iPhone6sPlus", "iPadMini4-iPadMini4", "iPadMini4Cellular-iPadMini4Cellular", "iPadPro-iPadPro", "iPadProCellular-iPadProCellular", "iPadPro97-iPadPro97", "iPadPro97Cellular-iPadPro97Cellular", "iPhoneSE-iPhoneSE", "iPhone7-iPhone7", "iPhone7Plus-iPhone7Plus", "iPad611-iPad611", "iPad612-iPad612", "iPad71-iPad71", "iPad72-iPad72", "iPad73-iPad73", "iPad74-iPad74"],
    "isGameCenterEnabled": false,
    "screenshotUrls": ["http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple128/v4/3b/75/42/3b754226-d1a3-d76f-f949-61f572afad7e/screen696x696.jpeg", "http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple118/v4/f3/2e/7d/f32e7de7-3e75-b950-aa65-fde00c0b9bf3/screen696x696.jpeg", "http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple128/v4/66/9a/13/669a13f7-d551-3953-e7e8-61e15a06ec2b/screen696x696.jpeg", "http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple118/v4/2c/9b/f6/2c9bf618-d557-8b45-0f03-5d15aacf9284/screen696x696.jpeg", "http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple118/v4/07/3a/95/073a952a-6e98-eeef-f7e4-4965b31c2de0/screen696x696.jpeg"],
    "advisories": [],
    "trackViewUrl": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/paytm-payments-wallet-recharges/id473941634?mt=8&uo=4",
    "trackCensoredName": "Paytm - Payments, Wallet & Recharges",
    "contentAdvisoryRating": "4+",
    "averageUserRatingForCurrentVersion": 4.5,
    "languageCodesISO2A": ["EN", "HI"],
    "fileSizeBytes": "131821568",
    "sellerUrl": "http://www.paytm.com",
    "userRatingCountForCurrentVersion": 16,
    "trackContentRating": "4+",
    "releaseNotes": "-You can now buy travel insurance along with your flight tickets!\n-Worry no more about your bill payments and recharges. Check out the order summary page when you recharge or pay bills next time to set automatic payments.\n-Get your Paytm KYC process fast forwarded by using your Aadhaar Card\n-Change in plans after booking tickets for a movie? No worries! You can cancel your tickets now with a full refund! \n-UX improvements and bug fixes.",
    "wrapperType": "software",
    "version": "5.12.0",
    "currency": "USD",
    "description": "#PaytmKaro for the fastest recharge, bill payment & shopping experience. Quick, easy and secure, Paytm is trusted by over 220 million customers. Recharge your mobile, DTH, data card or metro card & also pay postpaid mobile, landline, electricity, water or gas bills. For your travel needs, book hotels, flight and bus tickets. Also pay school or college fee along with insurance premium. Shop your favourite items at best price. Use any payment option or Paytm Wallet for maximum convenience. \n\nUse Paytm Wallet to send/ receive money, pay for services such as cab or autorickshaw fare, dine-in, petrol pumps & even at a local store near you.\n\nWhat We Offer:\nQuick mobile bill payments & prepaid mobile recharges for Airtel, Vodafone, Idea, Reliance, BSNL, Tata, Aircel, MTS, Uninor, MTNL & more at Paytm\nDTH Recharge for Airtel DTH, Videocon D2H, Dish TV, Tata Sky & Sun TV\nPay Electricity Bills (BSES, NDPL, MSEB, BESCOM etc.) and Water Bills (Delhi Jal Board) or Gas Bill (Adani, Mahanagar, Siti) for various boards \nLandline Bill Payments for Airtel, Reliance, MTS and more \nData Card Recharge for BSNL, Reliance Net Connect, Tata Photon Plus, MTS Data card to name a few\nInstant Educational Fee Payment – Pay admission fee or registration fee of various educational institutes and save time\nRecharge Metro Card Online – Say goodbye to queues, recharge your Delhi metro card or Mumbai metro card instantly \nAdd money to your wallet with debit cards, credit cards, net banking from all leading banks; transfer money to any Paytm Wallet\nPay with Paytm Wallet – Now pay using the Paytm Wallet on your favourite sites like IRCTC, Dominos, PVR and more. Also use the Paytm Wallet to pay for your cab rides at Uber, Meru, Taxiforsure or while booking an auto ride with Jugnoo\nMake instant payments at several local stores through the Paytm Wallet. Pay for Petrol at Indian Oil Petrol Pumps, your favourite food outlet like Vaango & many other local stores\nGold Loan & Insurance Premium Payment – Enjoy easy & seamless insurance premium payment and gold loan payment facility at Paytm \nMovie Ticket Booking – Book tickets for new releases every week\nBus Ticket Booking – Book bus tickets online in minutes at Paytm, pick your preferred seats and get set for the journey\nHotel Booking – Booking hotels has become a convenient task, plan your next trip with Paytm and book hotels online across India\nFlight Booking – Check fares across multiple travel agents and get best fares on domestic flight bookings\nShop On-The-Go – Buy your favourite gadget or discover latest trends in lifestyle, explore an amazing shopping experience for over 1,000+ categories\nHassle-free Returns on Shopping – Not happy with what you’ve got? No worries, we’ll pick it up from you, without you having to bat an eyelid\nGet Exciting Cashback on mobile recharges, bill payments, shopping & more\nOrder History – Now all your recharge, bill payments & orders will show up at one place, track or repeat them with ease in future\n24x7 Customer Care – 0120-38883888\n\nKey Features:\nBrowse Plans – View tariff plans on full talktime, top-up, 3G and 2G data recharge on all major prepaid mobile operators in India\nEasy & Instant Recharge – Use your phonebook easily to pick and recharge numbers, we remember all your recent mobile recharge, DTH recharge & bill payment for convenient one-click recharge experience\nScan & Pay – Scan & use the QR code to pay at your local stores or pay for fuel\nDownload this amazing app and recharge your prepaid mobile phones, pay bills of postpaid mobiles, electricity, landline, datacard & DTH for non-stop service and enjoy an awesome shopping experience with great value offers of your choice within one click, at great prices!",
    "artistId": 473941637,
    "artistName": "Paytm Mobile Solutions",
    "genres": ["Shopping", "Lifestyle"],
    "price": 0.00,
    "trackId": 473941634,
    "trackName": "Paytm - Payments, Wallet & Recharges",
    "bundleId": "com.one97.paytm",
    "currentVersionReleaseDate": "2017-08-15T03:10:10Z",
    "formattedPrice": "Free",
    "primaryGenreName": "Shopping",
    "isVppDeviceBasedLicensingEnabled": true,
    "releaseDate": "2011-10-24T23:18:48Z",
    "minimumOsVersion": "8.0",
    "primaryGenreId": 6024,
    "sellerName": "PayTM Mobile Solutions Private Limited",
    "genreIds": ["6024", "6012"],
    "averageUserRating": 4.5,
    "userRatingCount": 1688
}]
 }
```

while both app is lived on appstore.

Comment: [You really shouldn't force updates on users...](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/202866)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in your URL. When you want your app version and other details. You need to set url like https://itunes.apple.com/us/lookup?id=1240084177 like this.

You have to specify country code you will get all details like you want.

E.g. https://itunes.apple.com/in/lookup?id=1240084177